# 404 Errors on ONLY a few of my Flask Routes - No exceptions being thrown

Tags: python, flask, http-status-code-404

I have a user folder within the main application folder of my application, within the user folder is a init file, a models file, and a routes file.[File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMsE6.png)

My User class defines a signup method and within the signup method a user{} is defined.[Code from /users/models.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKgvd.png)

The routes.py file within the user folder defines a route to "/user/signup" but when trying to access this route, a 404 error occurs.[Code for routes.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9Xop.png)
[Image of 404 Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cmjB.png)

I get the same error from a route that is within the main app.py file, when trying to handle 404 errors.[Code from app.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rldx3.png)

Looked though for syntax errors or exceptions being thrown by Python or Flask, nothing is being logged as an error but still getting 404 errors on /user/signup and /404, /, and /dashboard throw 200s and load the html doc.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Ended up needing to completely close out the dev server running on local host, restart the application, then the 404's stopped happening.